# Index error: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

I have written this function:

```
def replace(self, pos, note):
    """
       Replace the score of the participant at the given position with a new score
       Input: pos, note - integer
       Output: the old score was replaced
    """


    scores = self.repo.getAll()

    scores[pos] = note
    return scores
```

Where getAll is defined in class participantRepo as follows:

```
  def getAll(self):
        return self._participantList[:].
```

My problem is that I dont understand the error I keep getting

Answer (score 0):

If list doesn't already have at least `pos+1` elements, `list[pos]` would try to assign `note` to an index outside the list. You can use the [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to add items to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If this code

```
scores[pos] = note
```

is causing this error:

```
Index error: list assignment index out of range
```

You might interpret it like this:

1. **list assignment index** refers to 'scores[pos] ='.
   'pos' is the index; 'scores' is the list name.
   You are assigning the value 'note' to the list at that index.
2. **out of range**  indicates that the number being used for 'pos' is not a valid index for the list 'scores' as currently specified.

One way to debug:

Add a print statement before the list assignment, to show you the value of 'pos'.  If you know the valid range of list indexes, this may help you trace where and why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should handle `out of bound access` as follows

```
def replace(self, pos, note):
"""
Replace the score of the participant at the given position with a new  score
Input: pos, note - integer
Output: the old score was replaced
"""
    scores = self.repo.getAll()

    if pos < len(scores):
        scores[pos] = note
    else: throw IndexError
    return scores
```

`